# CBlobCache usage - ATL Server Library

Tags: c++, caching, atl

Someone may have an example of use for CBlobCache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlobCache documentation and samples are [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/959f7k0f%28VS.80%29.aspx).